# Android How can i play shoutcast AAC, AAC+, MP3 in MediaPlayer for Android 2.3 and above?

Tags: android, stream, aac, shoutcast, aac+

I am developing a MP3 player, and I want to add radio features. Almost all StackOverflow posts about this are from 2010. This is very annoying for this topic, because I can't find a solution. I know that are commercial solutions, like AAC Player/Decoder and others. Can you give me some code examples instead?

Comment: What makes you think older SHOUTcast posts aren't relevant to you?  You realize that this kind of streaming has been around for over a decade, and hasn't really changed much, right?

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you mean ? And I don't think that is related with this topic. Probably the streaming hasn't changed but Android it changed to 4.0. Anyhow thanx.

Comment: The point is, if other solutions didn't work for you, you need to explain why.  Otherwise, at best you will likely get the same answers over and over again.  It is more likely (as you have seen) that you won't really get any answers.  Please read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I am trying to play a SHOUTcast via Android 4.0.3 with no success, too. I checked almost every solution related to the issue in stackoverflow. I believe that none of the solutions that are valid for previous versions work for the current version.

Comment: On my search for this topic i concluded that you can play shoutcast, but only the mpeg type not AAC, AAC+.

Answer (score 2):

Here example of a player: http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/

Comment: Hello dex, i knew about AAC Player all along but this is a paid version:"PLEASE NOTE that the use of this software may require the payment of patent royalties. You need to consider this issue before you start building derivative works. We are not warranting or indemnifying you in any way for patent royalities! YOU ARE SOLELY RESPONSIBLE FOR YOUR OWN ACTIONS! "

Comment: @dex Have you been able to play MP4-encoded AAC+ files with this project?  I haven't.